# A better method to detect phone notch?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have a method to detect the notch on iPhones and it works...but I just found out it doesn't work well. About 1 out of 5 app starts, I see the function reporting that the phone doesn't have the notch when in fact it does.

When my app deviceReady() state is activated, I then check to see if the device has the notch then assign the true/false value to a variable that I use later on.  As mentioned, about 1 in 5 times it returns `false`.  I think its a timing thing, the function is evaluating the DOM before the DOM has fully loaded causing the detection method to fail.

```
function hasNotch() {
  if (CSS.supports('padding-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom)')) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.paddingBottom = 'env(safe-area-inset-bottom)';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    setTimeout(function() {
      var calculatedPadding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(div).paddingBottom, 10);
      document.body.removeChild(div);
      if (calculatedPadding > 0) {
        errMgmt("preIndex/hasNotch ",101.1,"READY: Notch Detected") ;
        return true ;
      } else {
        errMgmt("preIndex/hasNotch ",101.2,"READY: Notch Not Detected") ;
        return false ;
      }
    },100) ;
  } else {
    errMgmt("preIndex/hasNotch ",101.3,"READY: Notch Not Supported") ;
    return false ;
  }
}

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $rootScope.hasNotch = hasNotch() ;
  ...
}) ;
```

Then in my landing page controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope,$state,$stateParams,$ionicModal,$q,apiService) {
   if ($rootScope.hasNotch == true) {
     .. do css stuff ..
   }
}) ;
```

When it fails to detect, its always the message `READY: Notch Not Detected` returned...not once has it returned the `READY: Notch Not Supported` which means the `CSS.supports` is working, but not part regarding the `calculatedPadding`.

The `true/false` value is needed in the Controller of the landing page, and when it fails its causing CSS layout issues.  Either the `hasNotch()` is too slow and the app init is triggering the landing page faster than the response from `hasNotch()` or there is actually something else wrong with my function.

On a side note, I have researched different methods to detect the notch on Android phones - the two plugins seem to have issues and/or aren't really supported anymore.  Was hoping for a solid solution for Android....or even better, a universal solution for both iOS types.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution but I still hoping there is a better way.  Something that can detect a phone `notch` during app initialization versus having to rely on DOM evaluations. I have tested the app over 25 times and so far this new method has detected the notch every single time.  As I code other things I will continue to evaluate the outcome, but so far so good. Here is what I did.

I removed the check from deviceReady:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $rootScope.hasNotch = hasNotch() ;
  ...
}) ;
```

And in my landing page controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope,$state,$stateParams,$ionicModal,$q,apiService) {
  $scope.hasNotch = null ;

  var watchNotch = $scope.$watch('hasNotch',function() {
    //begin watching for var change
    deviceData.hasNotch = $scope.hasNotch ;
    $scope.doSomething() ;
    watchNotch() ;  // kill watch
  }) ;  

  if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    $scope.hasNotch = hasNotch() ;
  } else {
    deviceData.hasNotch = false ;
    $scope.doSomething() ;    
    watchNotch() ;  // kill notch
  }
}) ;
```

Now I just need to go find a reliable plugin to detect Android notches....easier said than done.